# jquery lightbox expand across the browser window when clicked

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I want a button appear on an image.
When clicked on the button the image should expand across the whole browser window.
I think it does make sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#expand').on('click',function(){
  $('img#myImage').width($(window).width());
  $('img#myImage').height($(window).height());
});
```

**Demo** -->  http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/VWqum/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohammad Adil. It works. What if I want that button to restore the image's natural size when clicked after it zoomed across the full window? And Is there anyway to make it a popoup window? Thanks again.